# unstack start and end date to month

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
cust_id   start      end         subs_price_p_month     
1       2019-01-01  2019-12-10           50.00
1       2020-02-03  2020-08-05           39.99
2       2019-12-11  2020-11-08           29.99
```

I would like to "unstack" the table above, so that each row contains the subs price for 1 month:

```
cust_id   month        subs_price_p_month     
1       2019-01-01            50.00
1       2019-02-01            50.00
1       2019-03-01            50.00
....
1       2019-12-01            50.00
1       2020-02-01            39.99
1       2020-03-01            39.99
1       2020-04-01            39.99
....
1       2020-08-01            39.99
2       2019-12-01            29.99
2       2020-01-01            29.99
2       2020-02-01            29.99
...
2       2020-11-01            29.99
```

Text explanation:
Customer ID 1 has 2 subscriptions with different prices. The first one starts from 1 January 2020 until December 2020, second one from 3 February 2021 to 5 August 2020.
Customer ID 2 has only 1 subscription, from December 2019 to November 2020.

I want each row equals 1 customer ID, 1 month for easier data manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-srf.html) with an interval of 1 month and the range from `start` and `end`, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
  cust_id,
  generate_series(start,end,interval '1 month'),
  subs_price_p_month 
FROM t;

 cust_id |    generate_series     | subs_price_p_month 
---------+------------------------+--------------------
       1 | 2019-01-01 00:00:00+01 |              50.00
       1 | 2019-02-01 00:00:00+01 |              50.00
       1 | 2019-03-01 00:00:00+01 |              50.00
       1 | 2019-04-01 00:00:00+02 |              50.00
       1 | 2019-05-01 00:00:00+02 |              50.00
       1 | 2019-06-01 00:00:00+02 |              50.00
       1 | 2019-07-01 00:00:00+02 |              50.00
...
```

Perhaps even formatting the dates to 'Month YYYY' would better display your result set:

```
SELECT 
  cust_id,
  to_char(generate_series(start_,end_,interval '1 month'),'Month YYYY')
  subs_price_p_month 
FROM t;

cust_id |    to_char     | subs_price_p_month 
---------+----------------+--------------------
       1 | January   2019 |              50.00
       1 | February  2019 |              50.00
       1 | March     2019 |              50.00
       1 | April     2019 |              50.00
       1 | May       2019 |              50.00
       1 | June      2019 |              50.00
       1 | July      2019 |              50.00
   ...
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2fd0e0dc381bfca5e95062426c8a15a2)

Answer (score 2):

`generate_series()` generates the sequence of dates that you need.  However, it is tricky to get the date arithmetic just right for your results.

You seem to want:

```
select t.cust_id, yyyymm, t.subs_price_p_month
from t cross join lateral
     generate_series( date_trunc('month', startd),
                      date_trunc('month', endd),
                      interval '1 month'
                    ) gs(yyyymm);
```

However, if there are multiple rows within the same month, you would get duplicates.  This question does not clarify what to do in that case.  If you need to handle that case, I would suggest asking a *new* question.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=476102d9abc8b9446573b5d893250990) is a db<>fiddle.